# How to issue Geo Spatial Queries using Gremlin 3 via OrientDB 3.0.0m1

Tags: orientdb

I am attempting to issue Tinker Pop 3 Gremlin request via the Java API which references geo-spatial data. I am using Orient DB 3.0.0m1. A Vertex class named 'icg' has '*latitude*' and '*longitude*' Float properties defined. I am creating a spatial index as follows:

```
nodeClass.createIndex("icg.latitude_longitude", "SPATIAL", progressListener, null, "LUCENE", new String[]{"latitude", "longitude"});
```

I would like to do a Gremlin retrieval request which would get all Nodes which are within some Polygon. I believe it would need to use something like:

```
ST_WITHIN(xy,'POLYGON ((0 0, 90 0, 90 90,0 90, 0 0))') = true
```

In the context of Tinker Pop I would need to do  something like:

```
g.V().has(.....????; Or
g.V().where(.....????;
```

How would one issue such a request? And is this the correct way to set up the index?

Comment: Hi, have you gave a look at this link: https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Spatial-Index.html#how-to-create-a-spatial-index?

Comment: Thanks.. did take a look and was helpful, except had no info on how to use spatial in a gremlin query.